# IN/ON with Nouns

Tags: prepositions, nouns

I read in an article that *IN* preposition expresses a conditional state of being for example-

• I am in love
• This is the best option,in fact
• Call me in case you need my help tomorrow

And *ON* preposition is used to indicate a state of being or an intention such as in these sentences-
• I am on a diet.
• The office in on fire
• We are on an excursion to Paris

I would myself choose the same preposition in above-mentioned sentences , but it's still not clear to me what does it here mean by 'conditional state of being' and 'a sate of being or an intention' and for that matter what are the reasons for choosing the particular preposition (in/on)?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could cite the article you are referring to or link to it. It may then be possible to understand what the writer means by '_a conditional state of being_' and '_a state of being or an intention_'. Without further information, I can see no way that this distinction could aid in deciding whether to precede any given noun with _in_ or with _on_.

Comment: https://www.thoughtco.com/use-prepositions-with-nouns-esl-4177353 @Shoe here's  the link. As you will see their meanings ain't described here

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article. I don't think that the explanations and examples it gives are  helpful in answering your question "_What are the reasons for choosing the particular preposition (in/on)?_" For example, how would the distinction it makes between _in_ and _on_ help you understand why we say _in the morning_ but _on Monday morning_? The fact is that prepositional use is to some extent idiomatic and the learner simply needs to learn that we say, for example, _Who's that __in__ the picture?"_ but _Who's that __on__ page 30?"_

Comment: All such rules are always hogwash. All it takes is a single counterexample.

Comment: *On* your excursion to Paris, you are actually *in* Paris. You enter a church, and you're *in* the church. Then you enter the subway, and you are *on* the subway. Good luck with your conditional state of being.

Comment: If you get to the station on time, you're in time to catch the train. In a few minutes, you're on the train.

Comment: In fact, being in love is no more a "conditional state of being" than being on a train. Both are concrete realities and not conditional upon anything. Or, if "condition" here means "the condition (state) of being in love", then it's exactly the same as being "on fire": that's a state of being too. The entire article is bad -- it even uses *between* to define *between.* It does a grave disservice to ESL learners, its target readership, because they will simply be confused. Your question here is well-intentioned, but I fear you have been misled.

Comment: @Andrew Leach. Indeed! The article got off to a problematic start with the claim that "_Prepositions are easy to spot because they typically follow the noun or pronoun that they modify._"